# How do you play a song downloaded onto computer through command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know if I could play song I have downloaded to my computer through a command block to play it during the map.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a custom resource pack with the OGG sound files and replace the background music files with it.

Search up custom music on google for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Instead of telling OP to google it and figure it out themselves, why not explain it yourself?